# Node sequelize throwing undefined error when checking if an object exists

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Ok, so this is either very weird or I'm not understanding something that is happening. I am trying to load the sequelize library in node.

when trying to connect I'm using the CLI generated index.js file however this line:

```
if (config.use_env_variable) {
    console.log('i ran');
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
      var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.database, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
      dialect:config.db.dialect});
}
```

is giving me this error:

```
Cannot read property 'use_env_variable' of undefined
```

as far as I know that line is meant to see if this even returns anything so I don't understand why this is throwing that error?

**UPDATE**

config is invoked in a line above it, the whole file up to that point is:

```
'use strict';

var fs        = require('fs');
var path      = require('path');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var basename  = path.basename(__filename);
const config    = require(path.join(__dirname,'../config/config.js'));
const db        = {};

console.log(config);


if (config.use_env_variable) {
    console.log('i ran');
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
      var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.database, config.db.username, config.db.password, {
      dialect:config.db.dialect});
}
```

**UPDATE added console.log of config on working version**

Comment: config is undefined here.

Comment: config is definitely defined as when I remove the if statement and just use regular variables like config.db.username it's vaild. There is however no config.use_env_variable. I get why it's undefined, but not why its causing an error. Shouldn't the else clause just kick in?

Comment: I don't understand. In that screenshot you deleted, we can see that config has no property `use_env_variable`. And you could also see that sequelize was being initialized correctly (because of your else).

Comment: yep, I figured it out. I deleted the screenshot because I accidentally used the production set of variables and I cant' really have that sitting out on SO

Comment: So if you figured it out, what was the problem? =P

Answer (score 1):

After 3 days struggling with error, Today I was able to find a solution.

How did i solve?

I used JS trim() function to remove spaces.

for example

```
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "development"   // return false

  why ?

 "development " === "development"   // return false because of extra space
```

> process.env.NODE_ENV.**trim()** === "development"  //return true

Here is my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58139467/7522931)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have `config/config.json` file or the path is incorrect. In `model/index.js`, you would have this line

```
let config = require(`${__dirname}/../../config/config.json`)[env];
```

or something like that. Make sure this path is the right path

Comment: my config file is required. I'm just curious as to why the else clause isn't be skipped to?

Comment: Can you `console.log` your config object here